# How to change raster scale length in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I am trying to replicate the map of a Minetest server (You can see the map here: http://178.170.42.155:8080/#!/map/0/12/549/-295).

To position the raster, I used the Freehand Raster Georeferencer plug-in.
I added points from a database such as (0, 0), top-left, top right and so on to position the raster correctly with the freehand georeferencer. The raster fits correctly with the 4 diagonals ends.
However, I added some landmarks but they are off mark in QGIS. For example, the red cross on the website is marked as (517, -277) but the same point I added through database is off mark of roughly X=4, Y=20 in QGIS:

[image: QGIS Minetest Raster]

How do I solve this?